# Failed to execute script file (.bat) when running from a python script

Tags: python, batch-file

I'm trying to make a python script that creates a `.txt` and a `.bat` file, which in turn deletes the python script and then itself. However after the script creates the `.txt` and `.bat` files it comes up with `"Failed to execute script file"` error and `.bat` does not run. What could be wrong?

I'm using `pyinstaller` to package everything into a single `.exe` called `file.exe`. All files are in the same directory.

```
import subprocess
import time

###--- Create .txt ---###
text = "hello"
f = open("document.txt", 'a+')
f.write(text)
f.close()

###--- Create .bat ---###
myBat = open('C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\destruction.bat','w+')
myBat.write('SLEEP 5 \n') # Wait to make sure file.exe is terminated before continuing
myBat.write('DEL "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\file.exe" \n')
myBat.write('DEL "%~f0" \n')
myBat.close()

time.sleep(10) # Wait to make sure everything is completed

###--- Run destruction.bat and exit ---###
subprocess.Popen(['cmd.exe','/c',r'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\destruction.bat'], stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
exit()
```

I tried both with cmd.exe to run the .bat and without cmd opening the bat.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? I am getting a hint of intention to cause harm.

Comment: @Gerhard Barnad Your hint is absolutely understandable. I am in the process of changing career paths to cyber security with a long term goal of penetration testing. I am a total beginner that reads a lot, but doesn't practice much. The books that I read introduce me to ethical hacking concepts, tools and possibilities and I'm practicing those concepts following the books. After reading CEH V9: Certified Ethical Hacker Version 9 Study Guide
Book by Robert Shimonski i felt that I don't know enough to fully comprehend the knowledge within, therefore I'm doing much simpler exercises such as this

Comment: Ok. May I suggest you consider downloading Kali linux VM and run on Oracle virtual box. It has loads of built in tools for pentesting. But to help with the current question, can you post your batch file code as created by the python script?

Comment: @Gerhard Barnad Thanks for the answer. I'm running Kali Linux on a vm and trying out the tools there. The bat file is 3 lines as in the python code, one under another, and if I execute it manually it works just fine. Only the python script doesn't want to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try please. You do not really need to do all the timeouts as this really does run fairly quickly, but I retained them regardless.

```
import subprocess
import time

###--- Create .txt ---###
text = "hello"
f = open("document.txt", 'a+')
f.write(text)
f.close()

###--- Create .bat ---###
myBat = open('C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\destruction.bat','w+')
myBat.write('timeout /t 1 \n') # Wait to make sure file.exe is terminated before continuing
myBat.write('(del /q "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\file.exe" "%~f0")>nul >2^&1 & exit\n')
myBat.close()

time.sleep(3) # Wait to make sure everything is completed
###--- Run destruction.bat and exit ---###
subprocess.Popen([C:\Users\Me\Desktop\destruction.bat'])
exit()
```

I would also initiate the script as such for testing purpose.

```
cmd /c start "" python yourpythonfile.py
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer again! I tried your code, but it returns truncated error for the subprocess.Popen line, I think it's because it's missing "r" at the beginning. I added the "r" and run it through cmd as suggested, but then it comes back with "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified" for the destruction.bat. I also tried without "r" and with "\\", but again, file not found occurs. I assume this worked for you, so it must not be a code, but system related error. I'm just gonna practice other things. Thank you for your time!